# Access Java EE monitoring data inside a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, monitoring

I'm trying to access the monitoring data that glassfish v3 is collecting after i switched on monitoring service on and mbean service on.

I would like to show data like ProcessingTime or RequestCount in a "QuickInfo" servlet on the same machine to show the users/admins if the machine is busy.

I think the entrance into the data is probably InitalContext JNDI ... but i could not find a example.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To troubleshoot and find the exact names of the data you are interested in use this command:

```
asadmin get -m pattern-here
asadmin get -m "server.web.request.*"   # for example
```

You need one dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.flashlight</groupId>
        <artifactId>flashlight-framework</artifactId>
        <version>3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

For version use whatever version of GlassFish you are using.

The output is a bit messy but it will give you an idea.

```
import org.glassfish.flashlight.MonitoringRuntimeDataRegistry;
import org.glassfish.flashlight.datatree.TreeNode;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Resource
private MonitoringRuntimeDataRegistry datareg;

private String showOneNode() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<ul>\n");
    TreeNode mainNode = datareg.get("server");
    List<TreeNode> ltn = mainNode.getNodes("server.web.request.*");

    for(TreeNode tn : ltn) {
        String val = tn.getValue().toString();
        sb.append("<li>").append(tn.getCompletePathName() + val);
    }

    sb.append("</ul>");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

============

Links:

- [Adding Monitoring to Web Apps](https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/mort_learns_how_to_use),
- [How to get monitoring output via a commandline](https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/monitoring_data_how_to_open)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it working. I had to add the flashlight-framework.jar to my eclipse project. Now I get lot's of informations about server.web.* but how can i specify a specific bean or servlet?

Comment: take a look at the output of this command and you'll see how to do it:

asadmin get -m "*"